# How to model multivariate time series

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression, modeling, nonlinear-regression

I have a set of $n=1000$ samples of 4 dimensions (multivariate) where each measurement obtained from GPS tracking data is taken at a time interval representing spatial coordinates $(x,y)$, velocity. So, the data set contains 5 columns (another dimension for time) of 1000 tuples. Since there are 4 correlated vectors, then there should be 4 variables in the model each representing a measurement.

I am really struggling to determine:

1. How to begin modelling with multiple inputs and single output
2. Which model to choose?
3. Does the modelling choice depend on the probability distribution? If so then what is the relation?
4. Should it be linear or non-linear models?

Illustration with a small example will really be helpful.

Comment: You ask what model to use, but you do not tell what are you trying to model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose a vector autoregressive (VAR) model would be a suitable starting point. In  a VAR-model the dependent variable regress on lagged values of itself and the the other variables in your system (and possibly deterministic and exogenous variables),

Suppose $Y$ is a vector of your 4 variables, $Y=(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4)'$
then
$Y_{t}=\mu+\beta_1 Y_{t-1}+\beta_2 Y_{t-2}+...+\beta_p Y_{t-p}+\epsilon_t$,
the lag lenth $p$ could be suggested by the information criteria fitting to your purpose. It would be wise to do some unit root testing on your variables forehand, as the VAR assumes covariance stationarity. If several of the variables are found to have a unit root, they might also be co-integrated, in this case (of co-integrating variables) a Vector Error Corretion Model (VECM) would be more suitable. Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you for your reply.But I did not understand any of the technical terms.Starting with,in Y_t eqatuion, where would the values of y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4 fit as input?And what does unit root and co-integrated imply?

Comment: I'm sorry if that wasn't clear, by the notation I mean, you have 4 variables, $(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4)$ and they are all of lenght $n=1000$, is this correct?

Comment: yes,since there are 4 feature columns so I think there will be 4 variables.But in the equation Y_t there is only one variable which lags till Y_(t-p).So,how will the 4 variables fit in the equation as inputs?Or will there be 4 equations?

Comment: You regress your dependent variable on the lagged values of all variables: $Y_t=y_{1,t-1}+y_{2,t-1}+y_{3,t-1}+y_{4,t-1}+y_{1,t-2}+y_{2,t-2}+..+y_{4,t-p}+\epsilon_t $

Comment: Oh ok...so how to determine how many times to regress,what is the lag order and why should I choose this model?VAR closely resembles the AR model and the one in your comment above does not have \mew which makes the equation an AR model.So,is there any criteria for choosing a kind of model?I could have selected an ARMA model or MA model also?Could you kindly also give an example of the nonlinear version of the equation form?

Comment: When the deciding how many lags to include, you should try to get the best fit, according to the information criterion you have chosen, and see if it the model fulfills the model assumption. However, before you ask more questions I think it would be wise to pick up a book and learn a bit more about VARs and time series that way. I strongly recommend Applied Time Series Econometric, by Lütkepohl and Krätzig 2004. Good luck!